# C# weird behavior when adding generic to a collection of dynamics

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic

Works

```
private void Add<H>(H toAdd, IList<dynamic> list)
{
     list.Add(toAdd);
}
```

Doesn't work

```
private void Add<H>(IList<H> toAdd, IList<IList<dynamic>> list)
{
     list.Add(toAdd);
}
```

As you can imagine, the error is

```
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<System.Collections.Generic.IList<dynamic>>.Add(System.Collections.Generic.IList<dynamic>)' has some invalid arguments
```

If anyone knows why this is happening or even better, how to fix it, I am very curious. I assume it has to do with Generic Variance but the dynamic makes me less sure.

Thanks, Tom

**Edit**

```
   //doesn't work
   private void Add<H>(IList<H> toAdd, IList<IList<dynamic>> list) where H : object
   {
      list.Add(toAdd);
   }

   //works
   //this isn't good enough however because I only want to be able to
   //have one type of object in toAdd
   private void Add(IList<object> toAdd, IList<IList<dynamic>> list)
   {
      list.Add(toAdd);
   }

   //works
   private void Add<H>(IList<H> toAdd, IList<IList<dynamic>> list)
   {
      list.Add(toAdd.Cast<dynamic>().ToList());
   }

   private void Foo()
   {
      //works
      IList<dynamic> list1 = new List<object>();
      //works
      IList<object> list2 = new List<dynamic>();
      //works
      IList<IList<dynamic>> list4 = new List<IList<object>>();
      //works
      IList<IList<object>> list3 = new List<IList<dynamic>>();
   }
```

I added a couple more examples (not all surprising) just to illustrate

Comment: My first guess would be is that you are trying to add a list of lists to the list of objects

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you cannot cast an `IList<H>` to an `IList<dynamic>`. Imagine what happens:

```
IList<H> myList = new List<H>(...);
IList<dynamic> myDynamicList = myList; // assuming this would compile
myDynamicList.Add(new Foo()); // boom
```

You can try to keep a list of `IEnumerable<dynamic>` instead of `IList<dynamic>`, since `IEnumerable<out T>` has a covariant type parameter.

Comment: I'm not sure that it is that simple. For instance, I can do this: IList<dynamic> list ... list.Add("string"); list.Add(new Exception()); list.Add(new Foo()); and the compiler happily accepts this. It is unsafe but it accepts it nevertheless. So the question is not whether it is safe or not because as you pointed out, it is not. The question is why is the compiler complaining at all?

Comment: It is this simple. It's a covariance issue. You can cast `H` to `dynamic`, but you can't cast `IList<H>` to `IList<dynamic>` as it isn't covariant.

Comment: The only difference between IList<dynamic> list1 ... list1.Add(new List<H>()); and IList<IList<dynamic>> list2 ... list2.Add(new List<H>()); is that in the latter I am enforcing one extra level of type constraint. Also note that in Java, List<List<?>> list ... list.add(new ArrayList<H>()), compiles and works perfectly.

Comment: IList<H> could only contain elements of type H. You can never attempt to add elements of other types to the list, hence "boom". This is different from java since java's generics is not true generics. List<H> is actually the vanilla list and could contain anything.

Comment: As an illustrative example of what I am trying to achieve, imagine that you have a bag that only holds marbles and a bag that only holds dice, then you have a (larger) bag that only holds (smaller) bags with one type of object in each, however, the smaller bags do not necessarily all hold the same type of object. This is represented nicely but the examples that I gave that don't work and I just don't understand why it can't be done this way. Again, I'm not looking for the rule that prohibits it. I'm looking for the reason for the rule.

Comment: The larger bag (`IList<IList<dynamic>>`) doesn't hold small bags with one type of object in each. It holds smaller bags with *any* type of object in each. Since a small bag that only holds marbles cannot hold dice, it doesn't fit this definition.

Answer (score -2):

You are trying to add the list "toAdd" to the list of lists ("list")  and hence you see the error...

Comment: Provided they have the same underlying type, you can add a list to a list of lists. So that isn't the cause of the error.